# dockerでインストールしたwordpressがドメインで訪問した時にcssが読み込めない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wordpress, nginx

背景：

ラズパイにUbuntu18.04をインストールしてその中にdockerでwordpressをインストールしました。

dockerでwordpressをインストールした参考サイト
https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/

インストールして家のwifiではうまくつながってます、cssもちゃんとロードできています。

次にNginxでドメインとリンクしました、しかしドメインから訪問する時に下記エラーが出て来ました：

```
/wp-admin/install.php?step=1:8          GET http://localhost:8111/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.9 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
/wp-admin/install.php?step=1:9          GET http://localhost:8111/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=5.9 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

つまり`localhost`を探してると分かります。

Nginxの設定が原因かもしれません。
簡単な設定ですが、下記になります：

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name my.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8111;
        }
}
```

どうしたら直せるでしょうか。

Comment: domain + css のファイル名　はうまくロードできます、wordpress内の表記の問題かもしれません。

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  buttons.min.css:1

Comment: CSSが読み込まれないページのソースを掲示してみてはどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

質問文のメッセージより，インストールページにいると仮定します．

nginxで`proxy_pass`を使用する場合，別回答でも指摘されている通り，**proxy_passで使用したホスト名でリクエストが上書き**されます．

ただしく元のリクエストからHostヘッダーを引き続きたい場合，`proxy_set_header`で本来のリクエストヘッダーを引き渡します．

```
proxy_set_header Host       $proxy_host;
```

- [リバースプロキシ化したnginxでHostヘッダを素通しする設定 -- ぺけみさお](https://www.xmisao.com/2013/10/17/nginx-proxy-host-header.html)
- [Module ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header)

なお，`wordpress:latest`はApache HTTPDでPHPを動作させていますが，多くの場合nginxと併用する際はphp-fpmが好まれます(お好みで) ．

Comment: Nginxと併用したい時にはphp-fpmと書けば良いですか?

Comment: `wordpress:fpm`などのイメージが使用できます。なお設定ファイルの一例は[こちら](https://ja.wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/)

Answer (score 0):

以下の記述で localhost を指定しているのが原因に見えます。

> ```
> location / {
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:8111;
> }
> ```

Comment: それはリバースプロキシの文法ですが問題があったでしょうか？